# Oracle batch insert with date. How to format date?

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter

I need to batch insert into oracle. But the date is not formatted correctly.

```
$data[]=array(
        'USER_GROUP_ID'=>$wg_id,
        'MENU_LINK_ID'=>$id,
        'DATA_STATUS'=>1,
        'ENTRY_BY'=>$this->session->userdata['rrss_user']['user_id'],
        'ENTRY_DATETIME'=>"to_date('".date('d-M-Y')."','dd/mm/yyyy')"
    );
```

Comment: I am not a PHP expert but I observed one thing. The date format in PHP is d-M-Y whereas the expression used for Oracle is dd/mm/yyyy. Can you try changing the oracle date format to dd-mm-yyyy.

Comment: Actually date format is not a problem. When I try to batch insert query shows like below: INSERT INTO "USER_GROUP_RIGHT" ("DATA_STATUS", "ENTRY_BY", "ENTRY_DATETIME", "MENU_LINK_ID", "USER_GROUP_ID"
) VALUES (1,'5','to_date('27-Jun-2016','dd/mm/yyyy')','8','2')

Comment: Okay, so what exact issue are you facing. Does it throw any error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I am giving simple example please check this one my be help ...

```
$this->db->insert_batch()
```

Generates an insert string based on the data you supply, and runs the query. You can either pass an array or an object to the function. Here is an example using an array:

```
$user_id = $this->session->userdata['rrss_user']['user_id'];



  $data = array(
            array(
                'USER_GROUP_ID'=>$wg_id,
                'MENU_LINK_ID'=>$id,
                'DATA_STATUS'=>1,
                'ENTRY_BY' => $user_id,
                'ENTRY_DATETIME'=> date('d-M-Y') 
            ),

    );

$this->db->insert_batch('mytable', $data);
```

Now the above works fine, but if I try to change the date('d-M-Y') to anything more granular which includes hr/sec/mins

So it looks like since Oracle DATE type uses 'd-M-Y' as the default format, that's all it will accept as a string representation for date field...Would like to know if anyone has any thoughts on how I can set the field with the full date-timestamp, not just 'd-M-Y'.

Without Batch example :

```
$this->db->set('user_name', $name);
$this->db->set('age', $age);
$this->db->set('date',"to_date('$date','dd/mm/yyyy')",false);
$this->db->insert('mytable');
```

Comment: Solved. Thank you!

Comment: Shamminuj  Rahman  did you  used above  solution or any other ?

Comment: Yes, I used this date format for batch insert and it worked.

Comment: Another thing, can u please tell me datetime format?